# I am trying to design a basic CMOS Image sensor

Tags: sensor, design, cmos, photodiode, pixels

I am new to electronics so I might be doing some bad mistakes on my design but anyways,
I'm trying to build a CMOS Image sensor using Proteus, and I couldn't find some basic tutorial to follow, Yet I tried to do this circuit and it gives me errors
Both the circuit and the errors are attached as images
I would be very grateful if anyone helps.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: @jsotola yeaah I agree, but I figured that wouldn't change anything, would it ?

Comment: @jsotola I hope the edited version's better

Comment: it is definitely more presentable ... you can reduce the clutter even more if you replace the opamp pin 7 power connections with net name, same as the opamps on right side ... upvote for making an effort to present a good question

Comment: With simulators, compilers, etc.... always start with the first error reported.   Fix that, see if it got better.   Often, subsequent errors listed are a result of the very first error as it confuses the computer.   Contrary to what people think, computers are not smart.    What is "ON1' and why is not not modeled???   FIgure that out first and go from there...

Comment: @KyleB I see, good tip thank you, I can't figure out why tho since I'm new to proteus but I'll try